# ¿Porque no aparece mi nueva imagen creada?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con `django` el cual tiene un apartado con gráficos. Básicamente lo que hago al crear un gráfico, es generar y guardar la imagen de este y desde `html` o `javascript` las cargo (depende el momento).

El problema es que en teoría cuando el usuario crea uno nuevo, debería aparecer este nuevo gráfico y sustituir al anterior.

A continuación muestro la función que mediante `ajax` llama a la función de `python` que crea el nuevo gráfico y en teoría justo después lo sustituiría. Digo en teoría, porque el gráfico se me genera perfecto pero muchas veces no se hace este último paso y hasta que no refresco la página, no puedo ver el nuevo gráfico.

```
function graficos(node, day, month, select){
    console.log("Empiezo a obtener datos para graf bat");
    var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/../../graficos2/',
        type: 'POST',
        headers:{"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken},
        data: {
            'Node': node,
            'Day': day,
            'Month':month,
            'Select':select,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
                var resultado = response.Resultado;
                if(resultado == 0){
                    alert('No hay información para estos valores');
                }else{
                    $("#bat_graf").remove();
                    $("#bat_graf_container").append('<img src="../static/img/bateria2.png" id="bat_graf">');
                    window.location = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data_analysis/";
                }
        }
    });
}
```

Básicamente lo que hago es que el nuevo gráfico se guarda con el mismo nombre que el viejo y por lo tanto lo sobreescribe, justo después elimino la imagen del `html` y la añado de nuevo y cómo con esto no bastaba, refresco la página. Pero no sé si es por un tema de `cache` o que pero muchas veces no sale la nueva imagen.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que sí es por caché, podrías agregar un parámetro a la imagen para solucionarlo, tal vez timestamp de la fecha actual, algo como **<img src="imagen.png?nocache=8484744" />***